# Como implementar una clase singleton en C# Windows Forms para almacenar datos en una lista

Tags: c#

Implementa las siguientes clases:

- Clase Singleton llamada `AlmacenDatos` con propiedades de solo lectura para almacenar la lista de: `Ejecutivos`
- Utilizar la clase singleton en la manipulación de los datos.

1. Agregar 2 objetos a través de una de las propiedades de la clase singleton creadas.
2. Desplegar la información de los objetos contenidos en la lista 
   el codigo de mi clase ejecutivo es el siguiente:

```
public class ClassEjecutivo
{
    //propiedades
    public ClassSucursal SucursalDeAdscripcion;
    public string Nombre;// { set; get; }
    public string Apellidos;// { set; get; }
    public string Domicilio; //{ set; get; }
    public string Localidad; //{ set; get; }
    public string Municipio; //{ set; get; }
    public string Estado; // { set; get; }
    public string CURP; //{ set; get; }
    public string RFC; //{ set; get; }
    public string Telefono1; //{ set; get; }
    public string Telefono2; // { set; get; }
    public string Cargo; // { set; get; }

}
```

y mi otra clase se llama `DatosAplicacion`, que es donde almaceno la lista de mi clase ejecutivo:

```
public class DatosAplicacion
{
   static List<ClassSucursal> listaSucursales = new List<ClassSucursal>();

    public static List<ClassSucursal> Sucursales()
    {
        return listaSucursales;
    }

    public static ClassSucursal AgregarSucursal (ClassSucursal item)
    {
        listaSucursales.Add(item);
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Hola @ÁngelLuis. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cuál sería tu pregunta en concreto? ¿Podrías aclarar qué problema tuviste resolviendo el ejercicio y qué es lo que no te funciona específicamente?

Comment: eh pues mira @Mariano en definicion, quisiera que me ayudaran a implementar una clase  con el patron de diseño singleton a traves del uso de lista para que pueda yo asignar propiedades y al momento de ejecutar me devuelva los valores que introduje.

Comment: Te puedo pedir si podrás [edit] la pregunta con todo el detalle posible? Quizás te ayude leer [ask]. Por otro lado, etiquetaste la pregunta como "C", pero no es"C#"? (No son lo mismo)

Comment: Hola @ÁngelLuis exactamente no se a donde apuntas pero te dejo un manual del uso del patrón Singleton http://ltuttini.blogspot.pe/2011/07/winforms-singleton-pasar-datos-entre.html espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: Como dice @Mariano deberías de reformular tu pregunta y ser mas especifico en lo que quieres lograr, así los demás usuarios pueden ayudar a solucionar tu incoveniente y obtener respuestas mas rápidas

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas utilizar el patrón en tus clases el siguiente código te puede ayudar:

```
public class classToInstance
{
    private classToInstance() { }
    private static classToInstance _instance;
    public static classToInstance Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new classToInstance();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        //TO DO
    }
}
```

Donde al hacer utilizar directamente la clase instanciada lo puedes utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
classToInstance.Instance.Method();
```

De esta forma, siempre estarás utilizando una sola instancia de la clase en el código que se este ejecutando en ese momento.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí publico una idea tal vez te ayude.

```
public class AlmacenDatos
{
  private static AlmacenDatos _instancia;
  private List<ClassEjecutivo> ejecutivos;

  private AlmacenDatos()
  {
    ejecutivos = new List<ClassEjecutivo>();
  }

  public static getInstancia()
  {
    return _instancia?? (_instancia= new AlmacenDatos()); ;
  }
  //enviar un id único para diferenciar a cada ejecutivo
  public ClassEjecutivo getEjecutivo(string RFCparam)
  {
    foreach(ClassEjecutivo e in ejecutivos)
    {
      if (e.RFC == RFCparam)
        return e;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```